# Combining students into 3 groups.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Consider a class of 9 students. The instructor wants to divide the students into three
distinct study groups. Count the number of ways the instructor can accomplish this.

Four students in a group, three in another group, and the remaining in the last group

Comment: Do you want quick answer?

Comment: i want to know how to do it. I sort of get it but not completley

Comment: Then what have you got?

Comment: i understand how i would do if the 3 groups had 3 people in each. I don't understand how to do the different sized groups.

Comment: Go to [the question with identical wordings](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1046713/discrete-math-need-answer-quick) and read the hints.

Answer (score 1):

Let us say the instructor gives each of the 9 students a different number. The numbers 1, 2, 3, 4 go to group A. The numbers 5, 6, 7 go to group B. The numbers 8 and 9 go to group C.

There are $9!$ ways of assigning the 9 students a different number. Obviously it does not matter if a student goes as number 1, 2, 3 or 4 to group A. So we must divide $N$ by the number of permutations, which is $4!$. Similarly we must divide by $3!$ for group B and by $2!$ for group C.

The final result is $1260$. $$N = \frac{9!} {4! \;3! \;2!} = 1260$$

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check, how many possible groups with four persons exist. It it [of course](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) $\binom{9}{4}$.

Now he have to check three guys from group of 5. So we have $\binom{5}{3}$ possible groups. Two other persons make $\binom{2}{2}$ groups.

As we assign group of three to group of 4 and group with two persons to group with three and to group with four, we received that the [answer is](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=binom%289%2C4%29*binom%285%2C3%29) $1260$.

$$ \binom{9}{4} \cdot \binom {5}{3} \cdot \binom{2}{2} = 1260$$